# add an element in an array without position

Tags: c++, arrays, insertion

My problem is that i want to add an element without asking the user its element. I just want to add an element and when i print all the elements including the added one prints too instead of first asking its position and all.

```
int num,pos;
cout<<"Enter another element: ";
cin>>num;
cout<<"Enter position number: ";
cin>>pos;

cout<<endl;


for(int i=po; i>=pos; i--)
    a[i+1]=a[i];

a[pos]=num;
po++;

cout<<"New Array: "<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<po; i++)
    cout<<"Element at position "<<i+1<<" is "<<a[i]<<endl;
```

Comment: What's preventing you from accomplishing this goal?

Comment: Logic. 
If i delete the lines 
    a[pos]=num;
    po++;
the inserted value changes.

Comment: If you want to insert an element in the middle of the array, you naturally have to move the element that's there currently, and that may entail moving other elements and so on. If you have an array with 5 elements and you want to insert a new element at index 3, you have to move the elements at indices 4 and 3 to indices 5 and 4 respectively. You'd be better off using the `std::vector` container, which makes insertion simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array-like container that resizes on the fly as you insert items, use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  To implement something like this yourself, in a fixed-size array, you *will* need to do the bookkeeping.  Track your current insert position, so you know which elements are already used, and which are free.

Also, if you want to insert at the front, use a linked list.  Or use an array where you add to the end, so elements are stored in reverse order.  To print them, loop over the array in reverse order (from `pos` to `0`.)

Shuffling every element to insert a new first element is slow, and doing that in the common case is a bad design.